# storing elements in an array format

Tags: r

```
i am trying to generate subsequent entries for Sn with this relation Sn=Sn-1 +Xn 
   my Xn is (1x2) matrix
   Sn is (1x2) matrix
   yn is a scalar


y=numeric()
s=matrix(0,nrow=1,ncol=2)
mu=(1,0)
cov= matrix(c(1,0,0,1),2,2)
invcov=solve(cov)
s[1,]=c(0,0)

for (i in 2:10){
     x=mvrnorm(1,mu,cov)
    s[i,]=s[i-1,]+x
    y[i]=t(s[i,])%*%invcov%*%s[i,]
 }
```

i tried the code above and i keep getting this error message "Error in `[<-`(`*tmp*`, i, , value  = c(0.719138301056081, -1.96625516396033 : subscript out of bounds"

can i get any ideas on how to correct the error?

Answer (score 1):

You can't append to a matrix like that:

```
m <- matrix(0, nrow=1, ncol=2)
m[2,] <- c(1, 1)
#Error in `[<-`(`*tmp*`, 2, , value = c(1, 1)) : subscript out of bounds
```

You could use `rbind`, but it's better to pre-allocate (you know the final size of the matrix):

```
m <- matrix(0, nrow=2, ncol=2)
m[2,] <- c(1, 1)
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    0    0
#[2,]    1    1
```

That way you also avoid the Second Circle of the [R-Inferno](http://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf).